# Копирование в буфер в Firefox, Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, firefox

Добрый день.

Нужно скопировать данные с грида в буфер при нажатии кнопки. В IE все работает, но если попробовать скопировать в Firefox, Chrome, то вылетает ошибка `Error type: Clipboard Description: Access to clipboard denied`

Код:

```
setData:function(type,text){
    try{
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
    } catch(e){ dhtmlxError.throwError("Clipboard","Access to clipboard denied",           [type,text]); return ""; }
    if (!this._make()) return false;            
    this._p[2].data=text;
    this._p[1].setTransferData("text/unicode",this._p[2],text.length*2);
    var clipid=Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;
    this._p[0].setData(this._p[1],null,clipid.kGlobalClipboard);
},
```

Вопрос: как обойти эту ошибку в коде, чтобы не лезть в настройки браузеров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузеры не дают работать с буфером обмена, кроме IE. Но на помощь приходит флеш и zclip.

https://github.com/patricklodder/jquery-zclip

Answer (score 0):

В IE можно копировать в буфер, в нормальных браузерах - нет, это, видите ли, угроза безопасности (что недалеко от истины, но, как по мне, всё можно использовать как во вред, так и на пользу (тот же File API) - просматривать буфер обмена на наличие конфиденциальных данных или же копировать туда код примера или номер кошелька).
Хотя есть Clipboard API HTML5, но оно как-то не работает, каким бы бубном в любых арбузах я в него не бил.
Пока только флэш и надежда что API допилят до рабочего состояния.